# how to write url parameter to .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

From http://mardagz.net/view.php?year=2011&month=12&title=dear-christmas

mySQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_post WHERE year=2011 AND month=12 AND title='dear-christmas'
```

[MY POST WILL SHOW with title of dear-christmas]

but i want to rewrite
To http://mardagz.net/2011/12/dear-christmas

to secure... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (nb: in this rule I've forced the year to begin with "20" this implies it will work with years between 2000 and 2099 (which should be enough for you I guess)):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^20([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([a-z-]+) view.php?year=$1&month=$2&title=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Please tell me if it works

Comment: I hope I won't live *that* long ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ view.php?year=$1&month=$2&title=$3
```

Comment: Just fyi, I think that'll fail on something without a trailing slash.